# Round corners in connections between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

When connecting nodes in tikz, for example with

```
\draw (one-out) -- (two-in);
\draw (two-out) -| (three-in-down);
```

the connections usually have right-angle-corners with a sharp corner. Is there a way to make them more round? Or do I have to place arcs at those corners to get rounded corners in node connections?

Comment: `\draw[rounded corners]`. Btw please always post full minimal examples, not sniplets. Much easier for others to work with

Comment: Can I influence the radius for this option?

Comment: You can, see the manual

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned, please post full minimal examples. Options for rounded corners are found in the manual.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3,3);
  \draw[rounded corners=7mm] (A) -| (B);
  \draw[rounded corners=1mm,red,very thick,opacity=0.5] (A) -| (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your works. Very good. You are an excellent user +1.